# Trying to find a clever way to find indices of keywords in a given string

Tags: python

I know there are plenty of topics about finding indices of given keywords in strings, but my case is a bit different

I have 2 inputs, one is a string and another is a mapping list (or whatever you wanna call it)

```
s = "I am awesome and I love you"
mapping_list = "1 1 2 3 1 2 3"
```

each word will always map onto a digit in the mapping list. Now I want to find all indices of a given number, say 1, when matching the string.

In the above case, it will return [0, 2, 17] (Thakns @rahlf23)

My current approach would be zipping each word with a digit by doing

```
zip(mapping_list.split(' '), s.split(' '))
```

which gives me

```
('1', 'I')
('1', 'am')
('2', 'awesome')
('3', 'and')
('1', 'I')
('2', 'love')
('3', 'you')
```

and then iterate through the list, find "1", use the word to generate a regex, and then search for indices and append it to a list or something. Rinse and repeat.

However this seems really inefficient especially if the `s` gets really long

I'm wondering if there's a better way to deal with it.

Comment: Are you doing this many times? Or are you just concerned with `s` getting long? This is probably close to optimal, the only improvement I see is turning `s.split` into a generator for constant memory. tbh though, I kind of doubt this is a bottleneck.

Comment: I believe it should return `[0,2,17]`.

Comment: Or use a default dict

Comment: @JChao Did you try to time your solution with a really long string?

Comment: let's say there will be 1k of these `s`, and each `s` will be 50 to 100 chara long, after `split`, a typical length of the list would be 7 to 10

Comment: You want to find indices **in `s`** with respect to the "corresponding" occurrence of `1` in `mapping_list`? I don't understand why you would have to create a regex. you can just keep track of the current index in `s` while iterating over your `zip`.

Comment: @JChao Will the `mapping_list` be "shared" between different `s` values or you have `s` and `mapping_list` different each time?

Comment: @Bakuriu can you explain a bit more? using regex is just something that popped out of my head and I tried to go along with it before I encounter this problem(?)

Comment: @Bakuriu each s should have its own mapping_list in this case. `s` and `mapping_list` are output of a mysql query

Comment: @CedricZoppolo yea... actually with the given example, it takes on average 50microseconds, not bad at all. It's just that I'm running multiple for-loops and wonder if there's a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `map` the words to their `len` and use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), although you have to add `1` to each length (for the spaces) and add an initial `0` for the start of the first word.

```
>>> words = "I am awesome and I love you".split()
>>> mapping = list(map(int, "1 1 2 3 1 2 3".split()))
>>> start_indices = list(itertools.accumulate([0] + [len(w)+1 for w in words]))
>>> start_indices
[0, 2, 5, 13, 17, 19, 24, 28]
```

The last element is not used. Then, `zip` and iterate the pairs and collect them in a dictionary.

```
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for x, y in zip(mapping, start_indices):
...     d[x].append(y)
>>> dict(d)
>>> {1: [0, 2, 17], 2: [5, 19], 3: [13, 24]}
```

Alternatively, you could also use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) like `\b\w` (word-boundary followed by word-character) to find each position a word starts, then proceed as above.

```
>>> s = "I am awesome and I love you"
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r"\b\w", s)]
[0, 2, 5, 13, 17, 19, 24]
```

Comment: Thanks! these approaches look much cleaner than mine. I'm gonna do some quick benchmark though.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Find the indices of all the word starts
word_starts = [0] + [m.start()+1 for m in re.finditer(' ', s)]

# Break the mapping list into an actual list
mapping = mapping_list.split(' ')

# Find the indices in the mapping list we care about
word_indices = [i for i, e in enumerate(mapping) if e == '1']

# Map those indices onto the word start indices
word_starts_at_indices = [word_starts[i] for i in word_indices]
# Or you can do the last line the fancy way:
# word_starts_at_indices = operator.itemgetter(*word_indices)(word_starts)
```